# Chai check structure and values of return value

Tags: javascript, json, unit-testing, testing, chai

I have a few functions that I would like to unit test with chai, that are written before the functions are implemented, so they also serve as design guidelines.
As such I would like to make sure that the return value of these functions always follows an exact pattern, for instance this one:

```
{
  id: #some unkown UID,
  seller: 'user1',
  seller_offer: [
    {
      inventory: #some inventory uuid,
      item: 'red_card',
      amount: '11',
    }
  ],
  recipient: 'user2',
  recipient_offer: [
    {
      inventory: #some inventory UUID,
      item: 'coin',
      amount: '1234',
    }
  ]
}
```

The return value should never have any additional keys and contain all the required ones.
If all the return values were known beforehand, that would be easy to with a deep equal. Now the problem with this is that some of these values are UUIDS, which are obviously not known before running the functions. There are many functions like this.
I would like to be able to simply set the inventory and id values to null  so that chai ensures that the key is present, but doesn't actually compare its value (or maybe even a wildcard object that checks if the values are actually UUIDS).

Is there a way that I can do this? Basically ensure that the structure of the JSON is correct and simulatenously check some of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Chai JSON Pattern](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-pattern/) plugin to match the structure of the JSON. The API documentation is [here](https://github.com/damian-szulc/chai-json-pattern/blob/master/API.md)

E.g.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiJsonPattern = require('chai-json-pattern').default;
const faker = require('faker');

chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);
const { expect } = chai;

describe('67484029', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const obj = {
      id: faker.random.uuid(),
      seller: 'user1',
      seller_offer: [
        {
          inventory: faker.random.uuid(),
          item: 'red_card',
          amount: '11',
        },
      ],
      recipient: 'user2',
      recipient_offer: [
        {
          inventory: faker.random.uuid(),
          item: 'coin',
          amount: '1234',
        },
      ],
    };

    expect(obj).to.matchPattern(`
      {
        "id": String,
        "seller": "user1",
        "seller_offer": [
          {
            "inventory": String,
            "item": "red_card",
            "amount": "11"
          }
        ],
        "recipient": "user2",
        "recipient_offer": [
          {
            "inventory": String,
            "item": "coin",
            "amount": "1234"
          }
        ]
      }
    `);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks. Although its weird its handled as a string

Comment: @user2741831 If you know the version of uuid, you can use https://github.com/damian-szulc/chai-json-pattern/blob/master/API.md#uuidversion instead of `String`

Comment: I meant its weird the whole json pattern object is handled as a string. But I think it will work fine